# Error in rep(1:nrow(data), n[[1]]) : invalid 'times' argument

Tags: r, dictionary, import, purrr, rep

I am trying to import multiple files from a folder as separate dataframes to use for a time series.I used the code below:

```
df <-
  data_frame(files = list.files(path = "./yourfilepath",    
                                pattern = "csv", 
                                full.names = T)) %>%
    mutate(dfs = map(files, read_csv, skip = 25)) %>%       
    unnest() %>% 
    mutate(cities = str_replace_all(files, "./yourfilepath/", ""),
           cities = str_replace_all(cities, ".csv", ""))
```

But I got the error:

> Error in rep(1:nrow(data), n[[1]]) : invalid 'times' argument

I tried looking at other questions, but I was unable to translate it to my situation.

I don't what changes need to be done to the code to fix this problem.Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the directory exists? And has files?

Comment: Yes, the directory exists and has files.

Comment: Which line of the code chunk is throwing the error? If you run it line by line, what step doesn't work?

Comment: @Brian  It came from the last line ` cities = str_replace_all(cities, ".csv", ""))

Comment: The error is more likely to happen here: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/blob/037d8d964d46ad946584f0d58d6785a8264ca2e7/R/unnest.R#L134 . I'd suggest `debugonce(unnest.data.frame)` then re-running your code in RStudio, then step through the code of `unnest` and examine the values, in particular that of `n` (https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/blob/037d8d964d46ad946584f0d58d6785a8264ca2e7/R/unnest.R#L86)